# JS: Issue externally referencing object located within forEach loop

Tags: javascript, object, foreach

I am trying to run a function called updatePlayerFloor() that is run inside a forEach loop. In the function, I want to reference the player object properties from the updatePlayerFloor() function, but it throws an error when I try to do this.

```
    this.playerFloorDetect = function() {
        console.log(player.x); //test for referencing x property
    }
}
    mg_playerlist.forEach(function(player) {
        player.playerFloorDetect();
    });
};
```

The value of player.x has already been defined, as I have logged the value of player.x in the console from within the forEach loop, so it seems that the issue lies with player not being accessible. Is there a simple solution to this?

Comment: Try `this.x` instead of `player.x`.

Comment: Sounds like you want `this.x` inside the method